# Security in Angular: Addressing XSS Concerns with External Libraries and Interpolation

Tags: xss, client-side, secure-coding, angularjs

**Introduction:**

We heavily use external libraries, such as DataTables, in combination with interpolation. In Angular, we've identified two primary XSS prevention strategies:

- Interpolation ({{ }})
- Direct Sanitization with DomSanitizer.sanitize

**Concern:**

Concerns arise if these libraries misuse interpolation, leading to vulnerabilities. But, if we sanitize backend data with DomSanitizer.sanitize, special characters (e.g., Umlaute) appear as HTML-escaped and some info might be omitted which would have been needed.

**Potential Solutions:**

a.) Use innerHTML after sanitization with DomSanitizer.sanitize, risking overlooked sanitization issues.

b.) Process Umlaute with an encoding library to avoid property binding (innerHTML)

c.) Accept risks from external libraries misusing interpolation.

**Advice Needed:**

How can we ensure our application's functionality and security, given our reliance on external libraries and the challenges they present? **Is "libraries misusing interpolation" even a valid concern or is this technically not even possible in Angular?**

Comment: Realistically, (c) is your only option. You could potentially do some of your own XSS testing to gain assurance.

Comment: I think Angular has built-in protections for this... see here: https://angular.io/guide/security  "To systematically block XSS bugs, Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a template binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted values. If a value was already sanitized outside of Angular and is considered safe, communicate this to Angular by marking the value as trusted."